Can I install Lexical editor in my existing React project which made in lower version (<=16)?
We built the React project in 16.4.0. When I try to install the lexical editor, I get the peer dependency error saying that the React version should be at least 17 or more than that.
I tried to install almost all versions, but they have yet to be installed.
here is the link which I followed

Try this
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

